# Media foundation lossless video editing - understanding the IMFStreamSink

Tags: c++, video, ms-media-foundation

Yeah o'kei, seriously, this is my first attempt to employ Media Foundation MP4 media sink:

(simplified)

```
IMFSourceReader * pReader;
MFCreateSourceReaderFromURL( filename,0,&pReader );

IMFMediaType * pType;
MFCreateMediaType( &pType );
pType->SetGUID( MF_MT_MAJOR_TYPE, MFMediaType_Video );
pType->SetGUID( MF_MT_SUBTYPE, MFVideoFormat_H264 );
pReader->SetCurrentMediaType( /*...*/, pType );

//...
//IMFByteStream * pByteStream
IMFMediaSink * pSink;
MFCreateMPEG4MediaSink( pByteStream, MFVideoFormat_H264, 0, &pSink );
//...

//IMFPresentationClock * pClock
pClock->Start( 0 );

for ( int i=0; i<32; ++i )
{
    IMFSample * pSample=0;
    hr=pSourceReader->ReadSample( /*...*/, &pSample );
    if ( SUCCEEDED( hr ))
        hr=pSink->ProcessSample( pSample );
    SAFE_RELEASE( pSample );
    if ( FAILED(hr) )
        break;
}
pClock-Stop();
```

So what I got is `S_OK` until the very end of the program. Size of the samples read yields as 399 271 bytes but the size written to the file is only 300 745 bytes. Something has obviously being written but not sure what it is??

I've already written a wrapper for the MP4 reader part, so I should know: trying to open my very own MP4 gives me error

`MF_E_UNSUPPORTED_BYTESTREAM_TYPE`

What worries me is the *pull model* used by the MF media sinks. Frankly, I'm trying to implement a wrapper for which a push model would be favored.

I'm learning, but any advice for this simple lossless (no recompression, editing ~ cutting) writer would be greatly appreciated. Do I stand a chance to get it working using the plain for loop as depicted?

Comment: Do you correctly finalize and shutdown the sink? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms701626(v=vs.85).aspx#finalizing

Comment: @MikeVine Thanks, that did it. Your welcome to briefly rephrase that as an answer. :)